# ModuleNotFound : No module named "git"

Tags: python-3.x, git

I was updating my git repo using the below command

> python3 helper.py --update SomeName

But it is showing error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helper.py", line 13, in <module>
          import git
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'git'
```

I have installed both Python 3 (3.8.5) and Python 2 (2.7.18).

Comment: `python3` is telling you it can't find the module `git`. You need to install that python module.

Comment: How to install it?

Comment: I'd try `pip3 install python-git` but check your manual on how and where to install python modules.

Answer (score 8):

Following [Installing GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#installing-gitpython), a simple `pip install GitPython` should be enough.

If not, check [gitpython-developers/GitPython issue 1051](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1051):

> Even though I don't know what is causing this I do know that GitPython 2.x is supposed to work with Python 2 and 3, whereas GitPython 3 only works with Python 3.
>
> It's hard to understand what exactly happened here, but when running pip3 install GitPython I am also unable to successfully run `import git`.
>
> My best guess is that pip installs things outside of the PYTHONPATH, which certainly is surprising

Answer (score 8):

What worked in my case, on Windows, was

```
python3 -m pip install gitpython
```

Even after installing `GitPython` through `pip3`, the module was not being found, even if I included the appropriate paths. What worked is the command I mention.